# turtlebot3 navigation parameters

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, parameters, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to change a turtlebot3 navigation parameter called "inflation radius", I don't know how to actually go into the required yaml file to do so. I'm just confused. A book on programming the Turtlebot3 doesn't explain how to do so.
The book just gives the following  instructions:
" ...The following is the parameter setting for the TurtleBot3 Burger........
..... turtlebot3_navigation/param/costmap_common_params_burger.yaml". As seen, the instructions give the path,but I dont know where in my computer I can find this path.
I have already looked at the ROS navigation stack wiki, it doesn't help at all. Please anyone with experience using Turtlebot3, please reply

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383119/turtlebot3-navigation-parameters/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2021-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Mike Scheutzow I figured out my problem and it works now! I had duplicate files of turtlebot3_navigation in different places

---

Originally posted by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) with karma: 167 on 2021-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you set up this tutorial, you should have created a `catkin_ws/src` directory, then used git to clone `turtlebot3_navigation` inside of the `src` dir. That is the `turtlebot3_navigation` directory the book is referring to.

You don't say what OS you're using, but on Ubuntu it is common to put it at:

`$HOME/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_navigation`

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2021-07-25**:
gedit or nano may be used to edit this file and change your parameter. It's just a text file with a yaml extension.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2021-09-04**:
@Mike Scheutzow I have the navigation stack, I tried changing the inflation radius in the common_costmap_params and it literally doesn't do anything. I have the package i  the directory you suggested. I dont know what I am doing wrong. I am in gazebo simulation right now. Maybe this is why?Maybe it would work in real life?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-04**:
Please create a new question for this. Make sure to tell us what is working, then ask your question. P.S. Unless you say otherwise, readers will assume you are running Ubuntu 18.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2021-09-04**:
@Mike Schuetzow  I'll make a new question. Everything works and my Ubuntu version is 18.04. I just don't know why when I change inflation radius in the costmap_common_params_burger.yaml  nothing happens. I trying to change inflation radius of obstacles in a gazebo simulation so maybe that's why? Does the Turtlebot3_navigation package only work for the real life turtlebot3? Is there a different package I need to be looking into for simulations?